# How can I read the settings for the QgsPaperItem from XML?

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I saved a template qpt for the map composer and now I want to read all the settings. I am able to insert the items with composition.addItemsfromXML...
But this doesn't load the settings for the QgsPaperItem. 
This is the code:

```
composition = newCompView.composition()
file = QFile(self.plugin.rootDirectory + "ui/PrintTemplates/" + self.printTemplate)
doc = QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(file, False)
docElem = doc.documentElement()
composition.clear()
paper = QgsPaperItem(composition)
paper.readXML(docElem, doc)
composition.addItem(paper)
composition.moveItemToBottom(paper)
composition.addItemsFromXML( docElem, doc)
```

With readXML the paperItem remains empty. I just managed to set it manually in the code. But I want this to be loaded from the template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahoi, it would be good to know what version of QGIS you are using, and any other relevant particulars about your system.

According to the source for [QgsComposition.readXML()](http://doc.qgis.org/api/qgscomposition_8cpp-source.html#l00217) the paper info is stored in the `<Composition>` tag of the saved template (at the bottom). QgsComposition.readXML reads the attributes of that tag and creates a new paper item. To get to that tag you can use:

```
compelm = dom.elementsByTagName("Composition").at(0).toElement()
composition.readXML(compelm, doc)
```

However, this did not work right for me (Mac OS X 1.7.3, QGIS 1.7.4), *though it may for you*. Furthermore, the `QgsComposition.addItemsFromXML()` method is [commented out in the SIP file](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/python/core/qgscomposition.sip#L110), so I can't even access it via Python on my setup, or in my nightly master branch builds.

There appears to be a disparity between the methods of the C++ source and the Python bindings at this time, because a [look at the Composer's readXML() method](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/app/composer/qgscomposer.cpp#L1231) now shows it also taking care of addItemsFrom XML().

If my solution works for you, I don't suggest sticking with it. It seems there must be a different way to approach this using the API.

Alternatively, you could also parse the `<Composition>` tag's attributes yourself and recreate the paper via QgsComposition's methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am using QGIS Version 1.9.90-Alpha and Ubuntu 11.10. So it is a problem of the version - I guess?!
I used your code example and it is working now:

```
file = QFile(self.plugin.rootDirectory + "ui/PrintTemplates/" + self.printTemplate)
doc = QDomDocument()
doc.setContent(file, False)
docElem = doc.documentElement()
compelm = doc.elementsByTagName("Composition").at(0).toElement()
self.composition.readXML(compelm, doc)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Please consider upvoting and accepting useful answers to reward people who helped you.