# Qgis-How to make multiple print composers with one drawing using python

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to build multiple print composers but most of the sheets that I have to work with use the same layers with an exception to one unique layer. Is it possible to create one map document with all the layers I need and then distribute the layers to various print composers that I specify in code?

I think I am creating way too many map documents when I can just create one and a python script would automatically set up print composers that corresponds to a standard I specify. I am new to the qgis library for python. Is there any base code I can work off of or any useful links that I should see?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out those links.

[QGIS export composer as pdf in python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240983/qgis-export-composer-as-pdf-in-python)

[Saving Map Canvas as PNG with transparent background programmatically with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/135768/saving-map-canvas-as-png-with-transparent-background-programmatically-with-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to programmatically export a composition as image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103128/how-to-programmatically-export-a-composition-as-image?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to fill composer map with canvas data and export composition as png using Python script in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177828/how-to-fill-composer-map-with-canvas-data-and-export-composition-as-png-using-py?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I am also stuck on how to create a map composer, add layers and legend to it and then output it (in pdf). Tell if you find out !